# Where am I going wrong in my cubic spline, work out a,b and c

Tags: numerical-methods

[image]

So I know $f^{'}_1(x)=6x+3ax^2$ and $f'_2$(x)=6x+3bx^2$

and  $f^{"}_1(x)=6+6ax$ and $f^{"}_2(x)=6+6bx$

Now, $f_1(0)=0$ and $f_2(0)=c$, therefore $c=0$

And $f^{"}_1(0)=0$  and $f^{"}_2(0)=0$

But they don't seem to help me solve for a and b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, $f''(0) \neq 0$.

You need the following conditions instead, for it to be a cubic spline:
$$ f'_1(0)=f'_2(0)$$
$$ f''_1(0)=f''_2(0)$$
And since it must be natural:
$$ f''_1(-1)=0=f''_2(1) $$

These will let you find $a, b$ and $c$.

Comment: When I do that all I get is a=b.

Comment: @anna_xox Yup, sorry, edited :)

Comment: So then a=1,b=-1,c=0? And to verify continuity all I would need is to show the function values,1st derivative and 2nd derivative equal each other?

Comment: @anna_xox Indeed! You can check by plugging in the numbers and verifying that it really is a natural spline. Also, the problem looks poorly worded - it seems you should be able to find out a, b and c without knowing it is natural, and then check that it is, but I don't see a way to do that.

Comment: And to verify continuity all I would need is to show the function values,1st derivative and 2nd derivative equal each other?

Comment: @anna_xox In $0$, yes: you need to guarantee that it is $C^2$ everywhere, but the only problem point is $0$: everywhere else it is a polynomial, and thus $C^{\infty}$

Comment: Just wanted to confirm, is this reasoning right. 3x$^2$+ax$^3$=3x$^2$+bx$^3$+c at x=0 is how I get c=0. Since this is where the splines join, they will have the same function value.

Comment: @anna_xox Exactly. They also need to have the same first and second derivative, in order to form a cubic spline. As a side note, if you found my answer satisfactory, please mark it as accepted, so that the question isn't left open.